# different color for different range on x axis of line chart in flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

for different classes i have NSCC count ,now i have to make line chart showing this NSCC count falling in range like 1-10 is low risk,10-20 is moderate risk,20-50 is high risk and above 50 horrible.How to plot data with this range on x axis?And how to color different range width.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is use Multiple Line series with different Color

i suppose you have data some thing like this

```
|NSCC| |count|
  A      10
  B      12
  C      54
  D      25
```

you could convert to matrix like

```
 |NSCC| |count| |LOW| |MODERATE| |HIGH|
   A      10     10      null     null 
   B      12     12      null     null 
   C      54    null     null      54    
   D      25    null     25       null
```

and [create Multiple Line Series](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/11/13/changing-default-line-colors-in-a-flex-linechart-control/) on chart,
you may found split among series, to  overcome this you could add dummy boundry points

There are also other options like

- Use customize background with differnt colors
- Use customize itemrendrer

Hopes that Helps

Comment: i want single line with different colors for different ranges.i want something like http://stan4j.com/sample-report.html go down and see their are one line chart for data with the diferent range and is colored too.

Comment: yes you can do this as i told you, internally there is 3 series, but user would see only 1, draw first line from (0,y) to (10,y) and 2nd from (10, y) to (15, y) and so on...